# Android GLSurfaceView with drawable background

Tags: android, opengl-es, background, drawable, glsurfaceview

I have a GLSurfaceView with a drawable as background, however only the background is visible when rendered without surfaceView.setZOrderOnTop(true)

I need to avoid using setZOrderOnTop(true) because there are static TextView's being used on top of the GLSurfaceView.

Any suggestions for getting this to work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

GLSurfaceView cannot really have a background. The way a surface view works is by cutting a hole through your Activity's window and showing another surface behind. Setting setZOrderOnTop(true) moves the surface above the Activity's window.

Comment: Thank you that was very helpful!  Is there a way that you could recommend for achieving what I needed:   static background image -> 3d content -> additional views buttons on top  or is the only way to just render the static background as texture on a polygon?

Comment: I ended up just rendering the background on a polygon behind everything else.. thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 7):

false! You can do it.
Just an example to show how it works.

```
glRenderer  = new OpenGLRenderer(context);
view = new GLSurfaceView(context);
view.setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);
view.setRenderer(glRenderer);
view.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
view.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
view.setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_CONTINUOUSLY);
```

Then use framelayout to put a view under glsurfaceview!

Comment: Thanks. It made my GLSurfaceView descendant transparent. But actually REDERMODE_CONTINUOUSLY is the default value and for me adding the last line crashes the app.

Comment: That's because you have to setRenderMode before view.setRenderer

Comment: what to put in FrameLayout to keep the other views above GLsurfaceView?

Answer (score 2):

Try setZOrderMediaOverlay(true); which should put the gl layer above the background but below the window.

Answer (score 1):

Well, since GLSurfaceView is just another view, why not use a FrameLayout to place the GLSurfaceView on top of the ImageView (or whatever you're using to display the drawable.)

Comment: Tired it but it wasn't working because of the following conditions: 1. The gl layer has a constant background image. 2. there are additional elements on top of the gl layer such as buttons etc.   It wasn't possible to set the static image as a background on the gl layer because the actual 3d content would not render unless I setZOrderOnTop(true) on the gl layer.  But if I do that then the additional elements would end up under the gl layer.