# Draw line on background image, OpenGL Android

Tags: android, opengl-es

I have class that draws white line:

```
public class Line {

    //private FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;
    private FloatBuffer frameVertices;

    ByteBuffer diagIndices;


    float[] vertices = {
            -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
            -0.5f, 0.5f,  0.0f
    };

    public Line(GL10 gl) {
        // a float has 4 bytes so we allocate for each coordinate 4 bytes
        ByteBuffer vertexByteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4);
        vertexByteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());

        // allocates the memory from the byte buffer
        frameVertices = vertexByteBuffer.asFloatBuffer();

        // fill the vertexBuffer with the vertices
        frameVertices.put(vertices);

        // set the cursor position to the beginning of the buffer
        frameVertices.position(0);

    }


    /** The draw method for the triangle with the GL context */
    public void draw(GL10 gl) {

        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glVertexPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, frameVertices);
        gl.glColor4f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1f);

        gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_LINE_LOOP , 0, vertices.length / 3);
        gl.glLineWidth(5.0f);

        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    }
}
```

It works fine. The problem is: **When I add BG image, I don't see the line**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        glView = new GLSurfaceView(this);           // Allocate a GLSurfaceView
        //glView.setEGLContextClientVersion(1);
        glView.setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);
        glView.setRenderer(new mainRenderer(this)); // Use a custom renderer

        glView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_day); // <- BG overlaps my line
        glView.setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);
        glView.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);  

        this.setContentView(glView);   // This activity sets to GLSurfaceView
     }
```

How to get rid of that?

I'm sure it should be something simple.

Thanks,

Comment: You sure you want to use OpenGL ES 1? Why?

Comment: @StefanHanke does it makes sense? I don't see the difference

Comment: The difference to what? Are you learning OpenGL (ES) right now?

Comment: @StefanHanke Not at all, I dont have exp but try to rebuild my game after 2 years time break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place the `GLSurfaceView` on top of the activities window.
See [`setZOrderOnTop`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html#setZOrderOnTop(boolean)). Should be as simple as

```
    glView = new GLSurfaceView(this);           // Allocate a GLSurfaceView
    glView.setZOrderOnTop(true);
```

> Control whether the surface view's surface is placed on top of its
>   window. Normally it is placed behind the window, to allow it to (for
>   the most part) appear to composite with the views in the hierarchy. By
>   setting this, you cause it to be placed above the window. This means
>   that none of the contents of the window this SurfaceView is in will be
>   visible on top of its surface.

Related questions include:
[Android GLSurfaceView with drawable background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843853/android-glsurfaceview-with-drawable-background)